# How to simulate Redis Connection refused locally

Tags: c#, .net, azure, redis

Is there a value such as "MaxConnections" that I can set to "2" on my local redis so I can see how my app behaves on `get`/`set` that are refused?

I'm asking this because my app is supposed to run on azure and there, the redis instances have quite a tight limit of connections...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `maxclients` parameter to run redis server:

```
redis-server --maxclients 2
```

or set it in redis.conf

`maxclients 2`

> Set the max number of connected clients at the same time. By default
>   this limit is set to 10000 clients, however if the Redis server is not
>   able to configure the process file limit to allow for the specified
>   limit the max number of allowed clients is set to the current file
>   limit minus 32 (as Redis reserves a few file descriptors for internal
>   uses).
>
> Once the limit is reached Redis will close all the new connections
>   sending an error 'max number of clients reached'.

Also you can read [redis clients](https://redis.io/topics/clients).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my experience, currently it seems that we have no corresponding way to set MaxConnections value for the Azure Redis. From the [official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-configure#redis-commands-not-supported-in-azure-redis-cache) document we know that `config` cmdlets is not supported in the Azure redis.
I also try to modify the value from the Resource Azure, but it also **doesn't** work.

We also can give our [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to the azure team.

[image]